# How do I compare integer to JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, integer, jlabel

OK so I have these 2 labels where if both are them are 0, a button will be disabled. This is what I have done but didn't manage to do it, please guide me thanks a lot!

```
int quantity = 0;
int sum = 0;
```

I initialize them as 0, after that going through some IF loops and working well, and there's one event which is sort of like clear, I reassign them 0 again which looks like this:

```
quantity = 0;
sum = 0;
```

Then now I have 2 Labels which I want to compare to these 2 value, if both are 0, then disable a button, This is what I have done but failed ,the button still remained enabled. Then I realized I'm comparing to string 0 instead of integer 0, how can I compare it with the quantity and sum?? thanks  a lot!

```
 if ("0".equals(jLabel4.getText()) || ("0".equals(jLabel4.getText())));
    {
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: You can't compare a JLabel with an int. You can compare a JLabel's text with another String, but this has a funny code smell to it. You should compare ints to ints.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You want the button to be disabled when both of the `JLabel` values are zero, but you've a logical OR operatior.

Comment: Your code example refers to `jLabel4` twice. Is this intentional? Please be sure to copy/paste your code correctly if not. This also seems strange in general - `JLabel`s cannot be edited, therefore your code must already know what these values are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to compare integers, why compare Strings?

```
0 == Integer.parseInt(jLabel4.getText());
```

also surround it with `try-catch` block

```
boolean equals = false;
try{
     equals = ( 0 == Integer.parseInt(jLabel4.getText()));
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //equals = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, helped me out,well I'm still newbie to java, can't figure out what should I do to compare integer

Answer (score 3):

You should separate your gui code (the "view") from your non-gui logic code (the "model"). The GUI should display the state of the model, i.e., show in your JLabels the values held by the two ints of the model, but it is the model's ints which should be checked for 0 value, and then your GUI should enable or disable the button accordingly.

Comment: maybe because this does not give a real and concrete solution to OP question